# Fullcalendar color properties working only when allDay: true

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm only getting a background color when my object is like this:

```
   {
      title: "Conference",
      start: "2022-08-11",
      end: "2022-08-13",
      color: "purple", // override!
    }
```

When I have:

```
   {
      title: "Meeting",
      start: "2022-08-12T10:30:00",
      end: "2022-08-12T12:30:00",
    }
```

or even with:

```
    events = [...],
    eventsColor: "purple"
});
```

It's not showing any color. Color properties only work when I use `allDay: true`.

How can I use colors in `allDay: false` events?

Comment: This seems to be related to this two year old [issue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5743).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention it, but I assume you're looking at the default `dayGridMonth` view when you're seeing the situation you describe in your question.

If so, this behaviour is documented. The [eventDisplay](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay) option defines how the event appears in different scenarios. The default value is `auto`, which the documentation explains causes the following behaviour:

> When in daygrid, renders the event as a solid rectangle if it is all-day or multi-day. If a timed event, will render it with a dot. When in other views, will render normally.

So if you want to change this, you can simply change the option's value - for example:

```
eventDisplay: "block"
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/gOzZeQy

Note also though that if you set a colour on an event which isn't all-day, without using the eventDisplay setting, then adding

```
color: "purple"
```

to the event would still set the colour of the dot - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/abGPGoq

---

Regarding your other attempt, `eventsColor: "purple"` is incorrect. Again [as per the documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventColor), the correct option is `eventColor`. There's no such option as `eventsColor`, so that would have no effect.

If you set this correctly, then it works: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ExLGEqo (but of course it only sets a background colour if the event is being displayed in block mode. For other events, it controls the colour of the dot instead, as per my remarks above.)